# CheckedListbox Displaymember and ValueMember

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I have some problem with my Checked List Box.

```
public void GetFolder()
    { 
         var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
            {
             dict.Add(folder.Id.ToString(),folder.DisplayName);
            }        

       checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
       checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
       checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

    }
```

And now i want do get all Checked List boxes,

I do this with

```
         foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            lala = lala + item +"|";

        }
```

My CheckedListbox shows me the CheckIcon and the Name of all Folders that i read from Directory, and i want now to store tie folder.Id in some Settings but only the ID but i´m getting allways Foldername and ID together.

Hope Someone can help me
maybe i have some tomatoes on my eyes :)

Comment: hmmm where is my Welcomme message ?!

Comment: Welcome to the internet! You will find your complimentary pony to the left.. Be careful.. Rainbows come out of one of its ends! Haha I'm just joking! They come out ob both.

Comment: no in my post i have written "hey there" but cant see :(

Answer (score 1):

```
public void GetFolder()
    { 
         var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
         foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
            {
             dict.Add(folder.Id.ToString(),folder.DisplayName);
             arr.Add(folder.Id.ToString());
            }        

       checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
       checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
       checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

       //Do whatever to arraylist..
    }
```

This will give you an array list with all the ID's in it. You could bind that to a source, or run a `foreach` loop to get all the items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm asuming lala is your settings string.

If that is the case, use this:

```
lala = lala + item.Value.ToString() +"|";
```

This way, lala woud contain all the IDs like this:
1|2|34|567|5...

Comment: yes in my test form is stored in lala all checked ids.
but item.Value is unerdlining red

Comment: Sorry, it shoud be item.Value.ToString()

Comment: item.Value.ToString() Fails with:
object contains no definition for Value

Comment: If you still get [Foldername,FOLDERID_JHGD3287rHDGX73], then the problem is in your Folder class. Check it and see how the Folder.Id field is generated there.

Comment: OK, try Aram Beginyan's solution

Comment: foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
            {

                dict.Add(folder.Id.ToString(),folder.DisplayName);
                

                checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
                checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
                checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

and my CheckedListBox is filled with "dict" 
ID and DisplayName
i Read SelectedItems but get no ID Seperatly

Comment: hmm somewhere is a problem.
i can select some CheckBoxes if i Click my button with.

foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
lala = lala + item.ToString()+"|";
}
textBox4.Text = lala;
i got all selected boxes like:

[AAMkADE5YmIwZDA3LTdjMzAtNDZlOS04MDc3LTBhZWUyOGY1ZDQ2MgAuAAAAAACTXZc0AXhaQYCeWGlY9aKLAQANCS+7ujPFQpP5KZ/ydAp2AAAAEaCNAAA=, NewStorage]|[AAMkADE5YmIwZDA3LTdjMzAtNDZlOS04MDc3LTBhZWUyOGY1ZDQ2MgAuAAAAAACTXZc0AXhaQYCeWGlY9aKLAQC9TICb7ytCSbvH6E+KxFhrAAAARAjAAAA=,DeletedStorage]|
but often written i only like the Crypt Text .... 
later i check it again..

Comment: Check the other answer I posted

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this:

```
ArrayList folders=new ArrayList();
foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
            {
             folders.Add(folder);
            }    

       checkedListBox1.DataSource = folders;
       checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
       checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

foreach (Folder item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            lala += item.Id.ToString() +"|";

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i have a solution.

i use DataTable instead Dictionary

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
       table.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));

       table.Rows.Add("ID1=", "Folder1");
       table.Rows.Add("ID2=", "Folder2");
       table.Rows.Add("ID3=", "Folder3");
       table.Rows.Add("ID4=", "Folder4");
       table.Rows.Add("ID5=", "Folder5");
       table.Rows.Add("ID6=", "Folder6");
```

and now un Click all Selected Items i got

foreach (DataRowView objDataRowView in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("My value: " + objDataRowView["Name"]);
            }

only My IDs back :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
   DictionaryEntry de = (DictionaryEntry)item;
   string htKey = de.Key.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach, create a var item instead of object - you'll be able to access the Value property after that.

Comment: did you mean this ?

 foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                lala = lala + item.Value.ToString() +"|";
    
            }
also error

Answer (score 0):

Bind CheckedListBOx or any other control with displaymember and valuemember is quite simple you just need to specify  datasource property of control as well as displaymember and valuemember.

Following is working code 100 % work for me i have tested:P

```
/* checkedlistbox bindig code */

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string strChechboxlist = "select Subject_ID as code, SubjectName as Display from dbo.Mst_Subject_Detail";

/* filldataset() is function i have created to return dataset. */

    ds = dc.FillDataSet(strChechboxlist);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "code"; 

    }

/* for fetching valuemember or displaymember from checkedlistbox */


    for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
    {

    /*Now with the following code we can get valemember and displaymember as per your requirement you can store in table. */

    DataRow r;

    r = ((DataRowView)this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]).Row;  

    string val = (r[this.checkedListBox1.ValueMember]).ToString();  

    string dis = (r[this.checkedListBox1.DisplayMember]).ToString();    

    r = null;

    }
```

Note :- I am attaching working demo of code

Comment: i think you double posted/pasted.  this does not appear to apply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

//Here is an easy way [ I am new to coding ].

//The CheckedListBox can retrieve CheckedItems in the form a DataRowView

// For The CheckedListBox, make sure your datasource also passes an "ID" value.

// Setup the datasource for the CheckedListBox

```
     var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
        {
         dict.Add(folder.Id.ToString(),folder.DisplayName);
        }        


   checkedListBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
   checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"; //This will be the folders display name in the check box
   checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Key"; // this will be the folder's ID
```

// create a list to hold all the selected ID's

```
List<string> ListOfCheckedIDs = new List<string>();
```

// now get all the CheckedItems in the CheckedListBox as a DataRowView and use the ValueMember which contains the folder IDs to add the Folder IDs to the ListOfCheckedIDs

```
foreach (DataRowView drowVw in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)

        {
            ListOfCheckedIDs.Add(drowVw[checkedListBox1.ValueMember].ToString());
        }
```

// Now use string.join on the ListOfCheckedIDs so there will not be unwanted trailing characters

```
string myStringOfIDs = string.Join("|", ListOfCheckedIDs);
```